# phpMyAdmin - results empty when clicking 'Create PHP Code'

Tags: phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin, I am getting a blank page or empty results after clicking the link 'Create PHP Code' > No PHP code is being generated, containing the SQL query, as expected. I am inside a database with a table selected and have tried this from the Browse, SQL, and Search pages, wherein simple select statements are shown at the top in SQL or simple searches have been performed. In each case, 'Create PHP Code' only generates a blank page.

Version Information: Wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit x64 – Apache 2.4.23 – PHP 5.6.25/7.0.10 – MySQL 5.7.14 – PhpMyAdmin 4.6.4 – Adminer 4.2.5 – PhpSysInfo 3.2.5